# How to send / receive cURL/API requests in C#

Tags: c#, api, curl, webrequest

i have problems with my c# programm  to send or receive cURL requests to a online telephone system, i hope to get some help there :)

I want to send commands like this:

```
curl https://api.placetel.de/api/test \
    -d 'api_key=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX'
```

the server send in XML back

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
  <result>1</result>
  <result-code>success</result-code>
  <descr>test login successful v1.1</descr>
</hash>
```

i have try with the [WebRequest Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(v=vs.110).aspx) (msdn) but i don´t get a connection.

"Error System.Net.WebException in System.dll" Connection to server failed

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://api.placetel.de/");           
            request.Method = "POST";           
            string postData = "-d 'api_key=XXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX'";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            request.ContentType = "/api/test.xml";
```

there is a API [documentation](http://www.placetel.de/wiki/index.php/API_Dokumentation) from the telephone online system provider ,but only in german.

greetings

Comment: Your url is `https://api.placetel.de/api/test` not `https://api.placetel.de/ `

Comment: Since there were answers to your question you **should not** edit it to a new question. Instead, post a new question. You have just made the current answers obsolete. I suggest that you rollback your edit (via the "edited x time ago") and then post a new question with the new error.

Comment: Sorry :) i will do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer using *WebClient*

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
var buf = wc.UploadValues("https://api.placetel.de/api/test", 
                           new NameValueCollection() { { "api_key", "XXXX" } });
var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf);
```

or *HttpClient*

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>() { 
        { "api_key", "XXXX" } 
});
var resp =  await client.PostAsync("https://api.placetel.de/api/test",content);
var xml = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

which have methods easier to use.

BTW, `-d (or --data)` is a parameter of *curl*, it is not sent to server

*PS: You may also want to read something about `ContentType`  http://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html*

Comment: Sending looks like working fine - no errors. by receive the answer same error message - see edit above - thanks :)